# Looping ASCII characters and decrypting the message

Tags: c, char, ascii

My teacher gave me a homework: -

> You are given a string (of at most 100 characters) consisting of
> lowercase characters, terminated with a # symbol. The string is the
> "encrypted" form of an original string as follows - each character in
> the original string has been shifted by a fixed integer n (where 1<= n
> <= 25).
>
> Assuming that a is the 0th character in the alphabet, ..., and z is
> the 25th character of the alphabet, in the encrypted version, we have:
>
> 'a' becomes the nth character in the alphabet, 'b' becomes the (n+1)%26th
> character in the alphabet, ...
>
> and so on.
>
> n is not known to you. You only know that the first character
> represents 't'. From this information, you have to output the original
> string.

Here is my code for it: -

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char array[100]; //string will be stored here.
    char a;
    int i = 0; //initializer
    
    scanf("%c", &a);
    
    int counter = 0; // to count the size of the string
    
    while(a != '#')
    {
        array[i] = a;
        i++;
        counter++;
        scanf("%c", &a);
    }
    
    a = 't';
    
    int temp = a - array[0]; //To get the offset of the encrypted message.
    
    for(i = 0; i < counter; i++)
    {
        if((array[i] + temp) >= 'a' && (array[i] + temp) <= 'z')
        {
            array[i] = array[i] + temp; //Applying the offset to the encrypted message to get the true message.
        }
        
        else if((array[i] + temp) < 'a')
        {
            array[i] = 'z' - (temp - (array[i] - 'a')); //If offset is large and it falls below ASCII charater number 'a' then loop back to 'z'.
        }
        
        else
        {
            array[i] = 'a' + (temp - ('z' - array[i])); //If offset is large and it falls above ASCII charater number 'z' then loop back to 'a'.
        }
    }
    
    puts(array);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Now the logic which I have applied is certainly wrong. All of my test cases are failing. I suspect the problem is in the following snippet of the code: -

```
for(i = 0; i < counter; i++)
    {
        if((array[i] + temp) >= 'a' && (array[i] + temp) <= 'z')
        {
            array[i] = array[i] + temp; //Applying the offset to the encrypted message to get the true message.
        }
        
        else if((array[i] + temp) < 'a')
        {
            array[i] = 'z' - (temp - (array[i] - 'a')); //If offset is large and it falls below ASCII charater number 'a' then loop back to 'z'.
        }
        
        else
        {
            array[i] = 'a' + (temp - ('z' - array[i])); //If offset is large and it falls above ASCII charater number 'z' then loop back to 'a'.
        }
    }
```

I am not able to do this easy question. Please help.

Some of the test cases are mentioned below: -

[image: Test cases]

Comment: You have the formula `(n+offset)%26`use it. First translate range `['a','z']` onto `[0,25]`, apply the formula and then get back to `['a','z']`. Something like `((c-'a'+offset)%26)+'a'`. No `if` condition needed.

Comment: you are not making `array[i] = '\0'` after your reading is done. This will land you in trouble.

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès does your logic work if input test case is `zab#` ? I am not able to understand your logic. Can you please write a proper answer for this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char array[100]; //string will be stored here.
    int counter = 0; // to count the size of the string

    scanf("%s", array);

    while(array[counter] != '#')
        counter++;

    int offset = 't' - array[0]; //To get the offset of the encrypted message.

    if (offset < 0)
        offset = 26 + offset;

    for(int i = 0; i < counter; i++)
        array[i] = ((array[i] - 'a' + offset) % 26) + 'a';

    array[counter] = '\0'; // Removing the # at the end

    puts(array);

    return 0;
}
```

One, you weren't null terminating your string, hence the extra characters at the end at times. I fixed it by asking for a string instead of several characters in a row, which I find a lot simpler personally. It then adds a `\0` at the end of your array automatically, while it doesn't with your character by character approach. That being said, yours can also work, but only if you add a `array[counter] = '\0'` at the end to null terminate it.

> 'a' becomes the nth character in the alphabet, 'b' becomes the (n+1)%26th character in the alphabet, ...

Your implementation was vastly overcomplicated. A single line with `array[i] = ((array[i] - 'a' + offset) % 26) + 'a';` is all that's required here.

To break it down, we get the index of the letter in the alphabet by doing `array[i] - 'a'` ; we add the offset, we run a modulo 26 (the number of characters in the alphabet) to get the index of the new letter and to account for the fact we can get a result higher than 26 (in which case we want to wrap around : a 29 would mean the third letter of the alphabet, because 29 - 26 = 3). We add back `'a'` to get an actual character instead of an index, and we've got the correct letter.

Also, your code is currently susceptible to buffer overflows! You shouldn't care too much for a school project, but it's a gaping security flaw you may be interested in learning more about. You're also highly susceptible to a segmentation fault if there's no # in your input string.

I've purposefully not improved upon your code too much as it is a school project, but know the variable `counter` is wholly unnecessary, and you can redesign your code to avoid having to use it. You may want to think about how to go about this.

Comment: "Your implementation was vastly overcomplicated." Well, let's have a look at yours then. There is absolutely no reason to copy anything, or to loop over the string twice, or to use modulo. You could just do a replacement on the spot in the first go.

Comment: @OctaveL thank you so much for your insightful answer. Now I am able to understand everything. However I still am not able to understand how you took out offset, using only 1 line `(int offset = ('t' + array[0] - 'a' * 2) % 26;)`. If possible please do explain this also.

Comment: @Cheatah if you think that you are able to provide a simpler answer than the one mentioned above, please do post it, I am all ears.

Comment: @Cheatah I agree it's not the best, but I'd argue it's because I tried not to tweak the code too much. For instance, I'm well aware calculating ```counter``` is unnecessary, but I kept it because that's how Swarnim chose to implement it. I admit I should have made that clearer, but I'm not willing to provide a much better solution as this is a school project where complex code would stand out and make it seem like OP got handed out an answer. I am curious as to why modulo is unnecessary, though ; I considered a solution that didn't use it, but I preferred it as it's mentioned in the homework.

Comment: @SwarnimKhosla About that line; sorry to say I removed it from my post as it was invalid, or rather only worked for 75% of possible offsets. I'm convinced it's possible to do in one line without a ternary operator (which you may very well use here), but I have to find a better formula than this one. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: @OctaveL I can agree on the modulo comment. Since it's suggested in the question it's certainly the easiest to use. Will post a separate answer.

Answer (score 2):

The following is a simple inline replacement of characters by the desired offset. I have not optimised the replacement statement, because I think it's more readable this way.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char buf[101]; // one character extra for max input case
    char *p; // iteration pointer
    int d; // for "delta"

    scanf("%s", buf);

    d = *buf - 't'; // record the "rot13" encryption offset
    for (p = buf; *p != '#'; p++)
        *p = (((*p - 'a') + 26 - d) % 26) + 'a';
    *p = '\0';

    printf("%s\n", buf);

    return 0;
}
```

Remember: this is C, always be aware of invalid inputs.
With some basic error checking:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char buf[101]; // one character extra for max input case
    char *p; // iteration pointer
    int d; // for "delta"

    switch (scanf("%100[a-z#]", buf)) {
    case EOF:
        fprintf(stderr, "empty file\n");
        return 1;
    case 0:
        fprintf(stderr, "invalid input\n");
        return 1;
    }

    d = *buf - 't'; // record the "rot13" encryption offset
    for (p = buf; *p != '#' && *p != '\0'; p++) {
        *p = (((*p - 'a') + 26 - d) % 26) + 'a';
    }

    if (*p != '#') {
        fprintf(stderr, "missing termination character\n");
        return 1; // omit this line if you want best-effort output anyway
    }

    *p = '\0';

    printf("%s\n", buf);

    return 0;
}
```

This should deal with input that is too short or long, contains invalid characters, misses the # character or is simply an empty file.